# How to clear ViewState for UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have registered a usercontrol dynamically and called it in page load.
In Button click i used "Viewstate.clear" , for that usercontrol  but it is not working.
Can anybody suggest me to clear the Viewstate.

Thank u,

Comment: Perhaps, you should explain why you want to clear the view-state.